# Filtering/ORDER BY - Practice

Tags: sql, sql-server

I ran into a small issue with a order I am trying to do and not sure if there is a solution to what I am trying to accomplish. I have the following table created... CustomerID is PK and I can't change the numbers around.

```
Customer ID     ProductID     State
1   100 Alaska
2   100 California
3   100 North Carolina
4   100 South Carolina
5   101 Alabama
6   101 Virginia
7   101 Michigan
8   103 Hawaii
9   103 Kansas
10  103 Montana
```

The goal is to get the table to look like this:

```
1   100 Alaska
2   100 California
11  100 Delaware
3   100 North Carolina
4   100 South Carolina
5   101 Alabama
6   101 Virginia
7   101 Michigan
8   103 Hawaii
9   103 Kansas
10  103 Montana
```

The first part of what I'm trying to accomplish is adding the following record/row/entry (seen here)

```
11  100 Delaware
```

I was successfully able to add the row using INSERT INTO. The next task I wanted to accomplish was sorting (ORDER BY) the table by ProductID AND State. As you can see I am trying to move that new row to the new position as seen above.

As of now I have tried:

```
ORDER BY ProductID, State ASC;
```

My table looks like this

```
1   100 Alaska
2   100 California
11  100 Delaware
3   100 North Carolina
4   100 South Carolina
5   101 Alabama
7   101 Michigan
6   101 Virginia
8   103 Hawaii
9   103 Kansas
10  103 Montana
```

This changes the order of customer ID 5,6,7 which I am trying to avoid.

I tried to create a CASE but had no luck and wasn't able to "double sort" (error because my first 2 columns are int and can't compare to my 3rd column)

Any recommendations? Advice? Is what I'm trying to accomplish even possible?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: So what's the logic, if you are ordering by State then by what criteria should row 6/7 not change but row 11 can?

Comment: @Stu 
The logic is... if ProductID =100, then filter State in ascending order. not sure if i can target only the Product=100 entries (if that makes sense?)

Comment: You can do that with an extra ordering step, edit your question to include example data as *consumable* text, [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: "Delaware" is spelled wrong. Not sure if spelling is relevant here.

Comment: Also please post your attempt at a case statement.

Comment: @WesH `case` *expression* even :)

Comment: A table is an unordered set of rows. Only when selecting from a table, you can specify order. Anywway, what's the logic of your desired sorting? Why shouldn't 5/6/7 be rearranged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably this is what you are after?

```
select * 
from t
order by productId, case when productId=100 then state end,
customerId
```

Answer (score 2):

```
order by
    ProductId,
    case when ProductId = 100 then State else null end,
    CustomerId
```

You described how the table "looks" and how you want it to look. Understand though that from a SQL database standpoint there is no ordering of rows in a table. The order you are attempting to create applies only to output from a query.